# Dividing values from one array by values from a separate array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to take values from separate arrays and perform divisional math. I have created a method to perform the division, but I keep getting the "bad operand..." error. I have searched and searched, but cannot find resolution. I need to be able to take the values from tripMiles and divide that by the values from gallons.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Week6Challenge {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        int count = 0;
        //double miles = 0, gallons = 0;
        //Arrays
        String[] tripName;
        tripName = new String[11];
        double[] tripMiles;
        tripMiles = new double[11];
        double[] tripMPG;
        tripMPG = new double [11];
        double[] gallons;
        gallons = new double [11];

        //double miles = 0, gallons = 0;

        while (count <= 9){//start while
            System.out.println("Enter a description of this trip");
            tripName[count] = scan.next();

            System.out.println("How many miles did you drive?");
            tripMiles[count] = scan.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("How many gallons of gas did you use on this trip");
            gallons[count] = scan.nextDouble();
            count++;
        }//end while

        tripMPG[count] = answer(tripMiles, gallons);

        System.out.println("Trip Name \t Miles Traveled \t MPG");
        int k = 0;
        for(k = 0; k < 10; k++){
            System.out.println(tripName[k]+ "\t\t" + tripMiles[k] + "\t\t\t" + tripMPG[k]);
        }
    }
    public static double answer(double[] num1, double[] num2){
        return (num1/num2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the exact and complete error message, and tell us which line it refers to, instead of forcing us to guess. What do you think dividing [3, 42] by [2, 2, 2] should do?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to divide two arrays like:

```
return (num1/num2);
```

Which is not valid.

Instead if you need length or sum of two arrays and then divide, you could sum up all the elements and then divide the two values.

Answer (score 0):

You can't divide array like this `(num1/num2)`

Code snippet of one method how to do division of arraya

```
public static double answer(double[] num1, double[] num2){
   //assumimg both array is of equal length
   for (int i=0;i<num1.length;i++){
 double result = num1[i]/num2[i];
}

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As already been mentioned you can't divide arrays to each other, but their elements.

Change your answer function so instead of two arrays of double it takes two double and returns the result:

```
//num1 & num2 are double, not array
public static double answer(double num1, double num2){
    return (num1/num2);
}
```

Remove `tripMPG[count] = answer(tripMiles, gallons);` from right after the while loop and instead add the following line at the end of your while loop right before `count++;`:

```
tripMPG[count] = answer(tripMiles[count], gallons[count]);
```

So your while should look like this:

```
while (count <= 9){//start while
    System.out.println("Enter a description of this trip");
    tripName[count] = scan.next();

    System.out.println("How many miles did you drive?");
    tripMiles[count] = scan.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("How many gallons of gas did you use on this trip");
    gallons[count] = scan.nextDouble();

    tripMPG[count] = answer(tripMiles[count], gallons[count]);
    count++;
}//end while
```